# What would be the limit of f when x tends to the c value (-3)?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, absolute-value

[image]

As there's a white circle, that would mean our limit would not exist? Or, would it be equal to 3?

Comment: It means that the limit exists as $x$ $\color{red}{\text{approaches but does not equal} ~c}.$  Per the graph, the function is not defined at $x=c = -3.$  The limit of a function at a point can exist, without the function existing at that point.  That is why the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of the limit of a function **begins**: $$\color{red}{0 <}~|x-c| < \delta.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit is 3, since we are looking at the neighborhood, not the point itself.